# Using AppleScript automation how can I get currently opened Adobe reader file name

Tags: applescript, adobe

I tried below code

```
activate application "Adobe Reader"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Reader"
        set currentFile to active Document


    end tell
end tell
```

But I couldn't get active document name, I tried this code by already with opened document. I don't even find any dictionary for adobe reader in script Editor. Any suggestions will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The **Adobe Reader** app does not have an **AppleScript** *dictionary file* within it's *application bundle* and as such is not **AppleScript** *scriptable* beyond a very limited number of **Standard Suite** *commands* and **UI Scripting** its *menu bar* with **System Events**.

If you just want to get the *name* of the *document* that has focus, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*  can do that:

```
if running of application id "com.adobe.Reader" then
    try
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            set docName to ¬
                (get name of every menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item ¬
                    "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process ¬
                    "Acrobat Reader" whose value of ¬
                    attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" = "✓") as string
        return docName
    end try
end if
```

<sub>The use of `return docName` was for testing purposes and can be removed as appropriate. Additionally, it was not necessary for **Adobe Reader** to have focus and its *window* could even be minimized, the *script* still retrieved the *name* as shown on its **Window** *menu*.</sub>

- **Note:** This was tested on **macOS High Sierra** using **US English** and **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC** (Continuous Release | Version 2019.021.20058.) and works as is. Adjustments may be needed for other languages and or different versions of **Adobe Reader**.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few AppleScript options that may work for you. I don’t have Adobe Reader so I am not able to test the code.

```
tell application "Adobe Reader" to set currentFile to name of document 1
```

If that doesn’t work for you, you can try this…

```
tell application "Adobe Reader" to activate

repeat until application ""Adobe Reader" is frontmost
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to set currentFile to name of document 1
```

Comment: No this is not working , its throwing error "Adobe Reader got an error: Can’t get name of document 1."